# How can I use RSA signatures in powershell?

Tags: powershell, cryptography, rsa

I'm writing a powershell script where I need to verify the signature of a string using public / private key cryptography. I looked around and only found a "untested" demo of RSA implemented directly in powershell.

Is it possible to use a secure RSA implementation in powershell and if not, are there any other private / public key signature algorithms available?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use .Net objects in your script? Just instantiate a .Net [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) object and load your public and/or private key information. Then you can call any of the `Encrypt`, `Decrypt`, `SignData` or `VerifyData` functions, as you would in, say, C# code.

```
$rsa = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue>your public / private key info here</RSAKeyValue>")
$bytes = GetYourDataAsByteArray()
$decryptedBytes = $rsa.Decrypt($bytes, $true)
// don't forget to dispose when you're done!
$rsa.Dispose()
```

Comment: Any reason for the private key to be wrapped in an XML string?